# ssbo in my particles system is not updated

Tags: glsl

I work on particles system and I want to use SSBO to make update of velocity and position on my particles with compute shader. But I see for each update-call the compute use same values of positions but compute update position because in draw-call particles are moved.

Load particles into SSBOs

```
// Load Positions
glGenBuffers(1, &m_SSBOpos);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, m_SSBOpos);


// Allocation de la mémoire vidéo

glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, pb.size() * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


GLint bufMask = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT; // the invalidate makes a big difference when re-writing
float *points = (float *) glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, pb.size() * 4 * sizeof(float), bufMask);
for (int i = 0; i < pb.size(); i++)
{
    points[i * 4] = pb.at(i).m_Position.x;
    points[i * 4 + 1] = pb.at(i).m_Position.y;
    points[i * 4 + 2] = pb.at(i).m_Position.z;
    points[i * 4 + 3] = 0;
}
glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);

// Load vélocité

glGenBuffers(1, &m_SSBOvel);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, m_SSBOvel);

// Allocation de la mémoire vidéo

glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, pb.size() * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

float *vels = (float *)glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, pb.size() * 4 * sizeof(float), bufMask);
for (int i = 0; i < pb.size(); i++)
{
    vels[i * 4] = pb.at(i).m_Velocity.x;
    vels[i * 4 + 1] = pb.at(i).m_Velocity.y;
    vels[i * 4 + 2] = pb.at(i).m_Velocity.z;
    vels[i * 4 + 3] = 0;
}
glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
```

Update

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 4, shaderUtil.getSSBOpos());
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 5, shaderUtil.getSSBOvel());

    // UPDATE DES PARTICULES
    shaderUtil.UseCompute();
    glUniform1i(shaderUtil.getDT(), fDeltaTime);
    glDispatchCompute(NUM_PARTICLES / WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 1, 1);
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
    shaderUtil.DeleteCompute();
```

Draw

```
shaderUtil.Use();

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderUtil.getProgramID(), "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderUtil.getProgramID(), "modelview"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(View * Model));

    glPointSize(10);
    // Rendu
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, shaderUtil.getSSBOpos());
    glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void *)0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, NUM_PARTICLES);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
shaderUtil.Delete();
```

Comput shader

```
#version 430 compatibility
#extension GL_ARB_compute_shader : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object : enable

layout(std140, binding = 4) buffer Pos
{
    vec4 Positions[]; // array of structures
};

layout(std140, binding = 5) buffer Vel
{
    vec4 Velocities[]; // array of structures
};

uniform float dt;

layout(local_size_x = 128, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main()
{
    uint numParticule = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    vec4 v = Velocities[numParticule];
    vec4 p = Positions[numParticule];

    vec4 tmp = vec4(0, -9.81, 0,0) + v * (0.001 / (7. / 1000.));

    v += tmp ;

    Velocities[numParticule] = v;

    p += v ;

    Positions[numParticule] = p;
}
```

Do you know why it's happened ?

Comment: .Delete() and DeleteCompute() is for glDeleteProgram but i think it's not right in our solution to keep SSBO because glDeleteProgram frees the memory and it is not good.

And my bad for dt he's use but not in my copy normaly you have`'v+=tmp*dt` and `p+=v*dt`

But do you know why SSBO use previous data after draw call ? He might be reset somewhere ?

Comment: I don't recreate SSBO in every frame. They was created in main call.
`shaderUtil.Load("./shaders/vs.shader", "./shaders/fs.shader");
 shaderUtil.LoadCompute("./shaders/update_particules.shader");

 shaderUtil.LoadParticules(g_ParticleEffect.getParticuleBuffer());

    glutMainLoop();`

LoadParticles create SSBOs

Comment: Do you think `glutSwapBuffers();`and `glutPostRedisplay();`can reset SSBO ? they're called at end of draw call

Comment: hum that's weird... glBindBufferBase is called every update it's correct ? because i dont understand why it's good after compute shader update and after draw call with simple v/f shaders SSBO seems reset :/

Comment: My bad I used `glUniform1i` instead of `glUniform1f`for dt and he is float value :) and your help about Delete function has been very helpful. Thanks @Rabbid76